# How include LibGDX scene in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, libgdx, android-viewpager

Ok, I give up. I will tell you what I tried to do and hope for your help.
I want to create ViewPager with some scenes of LibGdx.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final int screenWidth = display.getWidth();

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }

        });
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        MyAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Fragment1();
                case 1:
                    return new Fragment2();
                case 2:
                    return new Fragment3();
                case 3:
                    return new Fragment4();
                default:
                    return new Fragment1();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for example Fragment1.java:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment1() {
    }

    @Nullable

    public View onCreateView(@Nullable LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_screen1, container, false);
    }
}
```

It works.

Now I want to use LibGdx instead layouts.

And I realized that I did not understand what to do next.
I found example at https://github.com/kbigdelysh/libgdx-in-fragment/blob/master/android/src/com/mygdx/game/AndroidLauncher.java

As I understand, I have to create FragmentLayout in xml file, but in example it does in main.xml:

AndroidLauncher.java (MainActivity.java):

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends FragmentActivity implements  AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks {
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        // Create libgdx fragment
        GameFragment libgdxFragment = new GameFragment();
        // Put it inside the framelayout (which is defined in the layout.xml file).
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                add(R.id.content_framelayout, libgdxFragment).
                commit();
    }
    @Override
    public void exit() {
    }


}
```

GameFragment.java:

```
public class GameFragment extends AndroidFragmentApplication {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // return the GLSurfaceView on which libgdx is drawing game stuff
        return initializeForView(new MyGdxGame());
    }
}
```

Of course, maybe I can use it in my Fragment1.java, but it extends from Fragment class.

I think, I should create new class extends from FragmentActivity like AndroidLanucher class, which will create new resource programmaticaly, which i will use in Fragment class.

But its very long chain and I afraid of making mistale. Can you say, is it right way? Or, please, give me advice.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: LibGDX uses static references to the Gdx classes, and therefore can only be used in a single view at a time.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I suggest using multiple instances of LibGDX. One for each fragment. I have not tried, but it seems to be possible.